# Query Parser Solr , Difference between standard query parser and dismax query parser

Tags: solr, lucene

I gone through dismax query parser and standard query parser and found the standard  query parser is different in handling error and hence more prone to error.so what are the different area in which one is powerful than other and what is the specific difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

> The key advantage of the standard query parser is that it supports a
>   robust and fairly intuitive syntax allowing you to create a variety of
>   structured queries. The largest disadvantage is that it’s very
>   intolerant of syntax errors, as compared with something like the
>   DisMax query parser which is designed to throw as few errors as
>   possible.

Standard Query parses is also known as Lucene query parser, so it's expect queries to be following correct syntax.

> The DisMax query parser is designed to process simple phrases (without
>   complex syntax) entered by users and to search for individual terms
>   across several fields using different weighting (boosts) based on the
>   significance of each field. Additional options enable users to
>   influence the score based on rules specific to each use case
>   (independent of user input).
>
> In general, the DisMax query parser’s interface is more like that of
>   Google than the interface of the 'lucene' (aka Standard) Solr query
>   parser. This similarity makes DisMax the appropriate query parser for
>   many consumer applications. It accepts a simple syntax, and it rarely
>   produces error messages.
>
> The DisMax query parser supports an extremely simplified subset of the
>   Lucene QueryParser syntax. As in Lucene, quotes can be used to group
>   phrases, and +/- can be used to denote mandatory and optional clauses.
>   All other Lucene query parser special characters (except AND and OR)
>   are escaped to simplify the user experience. The DisMax query parser
>   takes responsibility for building a good query from the user’s input
>   using Boolean clauses containing DisMax queries across fields and
>   boosts specified by the user. It also lets the Solr administrator
>   provide additional boosting queries, boosting functions, and filtering
>   queries to artificially affect the outcome of all searches.

For more information on Standard Query Parser - https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/the-standard-query-parser.html , on DisMax - https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html